# ModuleNotFound errorin falcon

Tags: falconframework

I am following the official falcon tutorial and there, they have used `waitress-serve --port=8000 falcon.app:api` to run the server. However, when I run this line in my terminal, it says

> There was an exception (ModuleNotFoundError) importing your module.

It had these arguments:

> 1. No module named 'falcon.app'

There's a falcon folder(the app.py lies here) inside falcon directory. When I go to the falcon folder then run `app:api`, it runs. I am so confused.

`app.py` file:

```
import falcon
from waitress import serve
from images import Resource
api = application = falcon.API()
images = Resource()
api.add_route('/images', images)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your falcon directory a package? Do you have a **init**.py inside the falcon directory? If not please make sure you have an empty **init**.py module insided your falcon directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
waitress-serve --port=8000 app:api
```

you don't need to specify the framework name. "app" is the name of the file and "api" is the name of object, you need to specify only these two things.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an empty init.py file in every falcon directory